# Why can't Safari open RSS feeds?

Tags: safari, rss

I'm using Safari 5.1.3 on Lion.

Each time I click the RSS icon in the address bar (or directly visit the feed), Safari will report can't open page, saying operation not permitted with the `NSPOSIXErrorDomain: 1` error. For other web sites, Safari works fine.

I have no 3rd party firewall installed on my system. I also tried to disable the firewall in system settings but still getting the same error.

As I use Google Reader, I've once installed the "Add To Google Reader" extension from Apple's site, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What exact version of safari are you running ?

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.3 on Lion.

Comment: Can you copy the URL and paste it into Google Reader?

Comment: Yes. Currently I just copy the URL and paste it into Google Reader. But this error is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, I tried the following command and solved the problem:

```
chown -R username: ~/Library/Safari
```

So I guess there are some files or directories which does not belong to me. It's weird how could this happen because I never touched that directory manually before.